# Find the encryption type with the orignal message and the crypted message

Tags: encryption, methods

Does its possible or does is a tool that can find the encryption method when we have the original message and the crypted message ?

Example : crypted message : ZHVoYW1lbA 
        : original message : duhamel

example2 : crypted message : ZmV5
         : original message : fey

Comment: In general, there's no way.  In certain cases one might be able to make an educated guess, but it be based more on the context than on the data itself.

Comment: Actually, it's not encryption, it's encoding, as Andrew suggests.  And it's plain-Jane [Base64](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

About all you can do is use the length of messages to work out whether it is a block or stream cipher (if it is a block cipher they will be multiples of some fixed size).  Even that requires some care as you need to guess whether IV and HMAC or similar have been used (for example, in CTR mode, the (so-called) IV is half a block).

If your examples are real, then that's not a block cipher, because the encrypted messages are too short.  And I don't really understand what the encoding is - normally an encrypted message is binary, rather than characters, so is written as a hex string or similar.  But your examples seem to be character strings.

So your examples are either made up or something unusual - more likely a "home-made" code than a standard algorithm used in software libraries.

**[Edit:]**  I'm updating this answer after working on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560948/encrypted-string-by-unknown-method#comment27312634_18560948

The above is talking about *encryption*.  Sometimes, however, what people are actually asking about is the *encoding*.  That is how the bytes in the (probably encrypted, but perhaps not) message are converted into something that is displayed or sent over the internet, or whatever.  This might be hex, or base 64, or something more complex like PEM.  Often you *can* guess this, because different encodings tend to look different.  Base 64 often ends with "=", for example.  And sometimes, this can give you a clue about the encryption used.  For example, PEM has distinctive header lines, which makes it easy to identify, and the default cipher for PEM in OpenSSL is triple DES, so if a file is PEM encoded, it's quite likely it's triple DES encrypted.

So given that, I should have included, in my original answer, the comment that encoding can also help guess the cipher type at times.  And in your examples, it's odd that both encrypted strings start with "Z".  But I don't know of an encoding that does that.

[see also related comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20217208/181772]

Comment: It is, indeed, simple Base64 encoding.

Comment: @HotLicks ha!  well spotted.  that explains the lengths.  i should have realised.